# Use my Swipe gesture function on multiple UILabels swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Im a newbie, ive managed to find and adapt code so that when i swipe a label, the value of that label changes. Now my func only relates to one particular label, but i want to make multiple labels have the exact same function, its a statistic taking label, how do i modify/apply the func to many different labels?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var kickLabel: UILabel!

    var counter = 0
    var swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let direction: [UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection] = [.up, .down, .left, .right]
        for dir in direction{
            swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.counterLabel(_:)))
            counterLabel.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
            swipeGesture.direction = dir
            counterLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            counterLabel.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
    @objc func counterLabel(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            if sender.direction == .right{
                print("Swiped Right")
                self.counter += 1
                print(self.counter)
                self.counterLabel.text = String(self.counter)
            }else if sender.direction == .left{
                print("Swiped Left")
                print(self.counter)
                self.counter -= 1
                self.counterLabel.text = String(self.counter)
            }else if sender.direction == .up{
                print("Swiped Up")
                self.counter += 5
                self.counterLabel.text = String(self.counter)
            }else if sender.direction == .down{
                print("Swiped Down")
                self.counter = 0
                self.counterLabel.text = String(self.counter)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `sender.view` will be the current `label` in your method. `let label = sender.view as! UILabel`.

Comment: Apologies for the newbie questions, but where exactly do i need to make the changes?

Comment: @JamesVanderhaak Code in my answer.

Comment: In `@objc func counterLabel(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer)` function instead of `self.counterLabel`.

Comment: you have to manage using tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` has the [view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624212-view) the gesture is applied to. Cast this to a UILabel.

(You might also want to check the gesture state for better performance.)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    var counters: [UILabel: Int] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for label: UILabel in [label1, label2] {

            counters[label] = 0

            for direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection in [.up, .down, .left, .right] {

                let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipe(_:)))
                swipeGesture.direction = direction
                label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func didSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        guard gestureRecognizer.state == .recognized else { return }

        guard let label = gestureRecognizer.view as? UILabel else { return }

        debugPrint("\(gestureRecognizer.direction)")

        switch gestureRecognizer.direction {

        case .up:
            counters[label] = counters[label] + 1
            label.text = "Up"

        case .down:
            label.text = "Down"

        case .left:
            label.text = "Left"

        case .right:
            label.text = "Right"

        default:
            label.text = "???"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying, but I’m having trouble knowing what you mean exactly, I’m very new with all of this.

Comment: Code added @JamesVanderhaak. :)

Comment: Thanks that has helped! Trying to figure out what it all means so i can understand it better. I am getting a few errors like: "Value of type 'UISwipeGestureRecognizer' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'" some ive fixed with optionals but some im not sure how to.

Comment: It should be a view, in this case the UILabel, that has a method addGestureRecognizer. Which you have correct in the code above, I think.

Comment: Yeah I cant get it to work... I put a screenshot below of what ive got  lack of experience is killing me

Comment: Apply the changes to the original code. Did this work?

Comment: Ok, the problem was with the counterLabel bit, so i deleted it and it fixed that, all the errors are gone. Now my only problem is, is that only label1 works, I dont know how to make the others work. I edited the screenshot above

Comment: I’m just working on a demo to get it going... bear with me.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help. Im sure theres an easy way to link as many labels as needed. I eventually want 20+ so the easier the better

Comment: @James I've updated the answer with working code. It's a little different to yours, but you just have to wire up the counters.

Comment: For some reason the simulator crashes now :-( actually fixed that. just gotta update the labels, i assume its like i had them before? update UILabel.text?

Comment: I think that will be unrelated to this  at least, it worked fine for me. Recommend creating a new clean project to verify this answer.

Comment: Sorry mate, its clearly something im not understanding, but now the label doesnt recognise swipes at all

Comment: @JamesVanderhaak comment the guard ... state == .recognized line. Maybe it’s a bit too restrictive.

Comment: Na still no good! Sorry for bothering you so much! I didnt think it would be this tricky, I had no chance on my own

Comment: Are the labels connected via Interface Builder?

Comment: ive got them connected as outlets above viewdidload?

Comment: Ah. I moved isUserInteractionEnabled and isMultipleTouchEnabled to Interface Builder. Add these lines back into the loop and it should work.

Comment: Yep the interaction now works! just need seperate counter variables for each label now!

Comment: Cool. Are we calling this answered now, given Swipe gesture for multiple labels are working?

Comment: Yep we can call it answered! Thanks so much

Comment: Hi Scott, how do I get help with the individual counters? Post another question? Im not sure of the ways and means of StackOverflow yet :-)

Comment: Probably, best. But in the meantime, I've added some code to help you out. Look for counters[label] in the code in the answer. :) (Quick code, no guarantee to compile just yet.)

Comment: I tried and its not quite worjing, i posted as a new question :-)